# empAPI - can't call subscribe method

Tags: lightning-web-components, streaming-api

Can anyone tell me why this code

```
handleCDC(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
}

subscribe(channel, -1, handleCDC).then(response=>{
    console.log('success', JSON.stringify(response.channel));
});
```

is illegal?
why I can't call subscribe method directly?

Comment: what is `channel` and where is it declared?

Comment: channel declared earlier in this model. I can't just compile this code